Doubts regarding Prahar's comments on two-point correlator of free boson in 1+1D
In this answer @Prahar says that for a conformally invariant scalar field in $(1+1)$ dimensions, corresponding to a free boson,
$$\log|x-y|$$
is the only dimensionally consistent equation for the two-point function.
I don't see why/how that is the case. For example, why isn't $$\sin|x-y|$$  allowed?
In the comments to that answer, he further says that we can see this by taking: $h \to 0$ limit of $$  \frac{1}{|x-y|^{2h}} \ $$
I get a constant instead of a log term here.
I am sure he might have meant something which is correct, trivial and enlightening to many, since there are $8$ upvotes (as of now), but I don't seem to understand it. Can anyone clarify what he means there?

See https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03959 for more careful statements.

I saw this reference at the link you mentioned in your answer to that question. Thanks for the comment: it is an honour. Btw @ConnorBehan I had a related question here which might interest you.

A free scalar field in two dimensions satisfies the equation $ \partial_z \partial_{\bar z} \phi = 0$. The two-point function of the theory must, therefore, satisfies
$$
\partial_z \partial_{\bar z} G(z-w) = \delta^2(z-w).
$$
The solution to this equation is
$$
 G(z-w) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln \frac{|z-w|^2}{\mu}
$$
where I have put in an IR scale to make the argument of the log well-defined.
As I mentioned, this can be obtained from a $h \to 0$ limit of the usual 2-point function, but one has to be more careful with the limiting process. The reference by Connor probably has the answer there.

Oh this I knew: when you said dimensional analysis, I thought that maybe the function $\log$ is itself determined by dimensional analysis. Also, I expected that you had a particular way of doing the $h \to 0$ limit apart from Connor's reference.

Also the factor of $\mu$ seems to be a typo in one of the answers by you. Either this or the one linked in the question. I think this one.

It's not a typo. The two $\mu$'s are not the same. The point is that it is an IR regulator.

Dimensional analysis cannot, of course, determine the function on its own. This is never true anywhere in physics. Some additional input always has to go in.
